# CSS extending background color to the right hand side of the page

Tags: html, css

With HTML such as

```
<code style="background-color: #FFFFD9">
some block
of code
</code>
```

Is it possible to have the background colour extend to the right hand side of the page (rather than just where the text is)?

I don't want to use <div> because the block of code is nested within a <ul> or <ol> so I want to preserve the white space on the left hand side of the code block at whatever level of indentation is present because of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another possible styling:

```html
<code style="display:block; white-space:pre; width:100%; background-color: #FFFFD9;">
some block
of code
</code>
```

Comment: Superb. I knew there had to be a better way of doing it than my kludge, which is why I did not tick my own answer as the solution.

Comment: Thank you, glad it helped ;) Also didn't know it, only checked the `<code>`'s properties in [Firefox Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) (Ctrl+Shift+i) and noticed it's by default an inline element. So have a good time :-)

Answer (score 0):

We would probably need to see a bit more of the markup and CSS, but have you tried simply setting the `width` to 100%?

```
code { background: #ffffd9; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: width would only work inside a <div>; which I could not use because the code block needs to be inside a list <ol><li><ul><li>. I have worked out an answer, see below.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer was to put the <code> inside a table that has just one cell. CSS can then be specified for the table that gives it 100% width, no margins borders padding etc.

This keeps the left hand indentation white from the <ol><li><ul><li> that the code block is placed in. The coloured background then extends to the right hand side.

CSS:

```
.tablecodeblock, .tablecodeblock td {width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0}
.tablecodeblock td {background-color: #FFFFD9}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tablecodeblock"><tr><td><code><xmp>Some block
of code</xmp></code>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Stano's answer below is a much better solution.